# Construct a binary tree using inorder and preorder with duplicate values

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, inorder, preorder

I was studying this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-tree-from-given-inorder-and-preorder-traversal/   but could not find a way to construct a binary tree using preorder and inorder **with duplicate values** because hashmaps and linear search does not work in some cases to find the right index. Please tell if there is an algorithm for this. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably you can add to a set that tracks already seen indices in case of duplicate values.

Comment: If all the values are the same, then the inorder and preorder traversals are the same no matter what the shape of the tree is, so the shape cannot be reconstructed.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I feel bad but you are right. Its not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, we can't create a tree from inorder and preorder or inorder and postorder if the tree contains duplicate values.